# How to add new columns in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to add new columns before late column.

Below query returns an error

*query*

```
ALTER TABLE mydataset.my_table
  ADD COLUMN col_1 FLOAT64,
  ADD COLUMN col_2 FLOAT64
  BEFORE last_col
```

The error i get is

> Syntax error: Expected end of input but got identifier "BEFORE"

Comment: What does the documentation say, is that BEFORE syntax supported?

Comment: Note that you have the same name for both columns.

Answer (score 0):

As said by [the documentation on ALTER TABLE for BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_table_add_column_statement), you don't have the 'BEFORE' keyword. Columns in a table are not ordered by default. You order the columns when doing SELECT on it.